# Centering Nested Relative layout in parent

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I have to make (sort of) footer for empty screen. My parent layout is `RelativeLayout1`. Inside this layout I have `ToolBar` and below that is another `RelativeLayout2`.

Inside this `RelativeLayout2` is Button and another `RelativeLayout3`. I made it that way, because I want to center `RelativeLayout3` content in `RelativeLayout2` and `Button` should always align bottom of the parent layout(`RelativeLayout2`)

I got answer for similar question before, but it doesnt always work. My problem now is that `RelativeLayout3` is off-centered vertically(it's closer to the bottom).

**How it should looks like**

[image: How it should looks like]

**How it actually looks like**

[image: How it actually looks like]

How to fix this?

Full Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_round"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolBarContent"
            layout="@layout/order_toolbar_layout" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/order_complete_footer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolBar"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/order_complete_image_text_layout"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/order_complete_image"
                android:layout_width="175dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:src="@drawable/footer_image" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/order_complete_text1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/order_complete_image"
                android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-12dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/order_complete_screen_text1"
                android:textColor="@color/colorItemMinor"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/order_complete_text2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/order_complete_text1"
                android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/order_complete_screen_text2"
                android:textColor="@color/colorItemMinor"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/order_complete_continue_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/address_creation_button_padding_TOP_BOTTOM"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/address_creation_button_padding_START_END"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/address_creation_button_padding_START_END"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/address_creation_button_padding_TOP_BOTTOM"
            android:background="@drawable/login_button_background_void"
            android:text="@string/order_complete_screen_button_label"
            android:textAppearance="@style/VoidLoginButtonTextAppearance" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you explain exactly where is the problem, It's a bit hard to understand your description :)

Comment: If I understood correctly, you should add             `android:layout_above="@id/order_complete_continue_button"` to your `order_complete_image_text_layout`

Comment: Added some Paint explanation :)

Comment: @martin1337 in that case you will need some improvements in your xml, using RelativeLayout is your requirement or you can use other layouts too ?

Answer (score -1):

If I understood correctly, you should add the following to your `order_complete_image_text_layout`.

```
android:layout_above="@id/order_complete_continue_button"
```

[@JanStoltman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6592863/jan-stoltman)